# JavaScript - Regular Expression with replace not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried a very simple regular expression.

```js
var name = "jon snow"

name = name.replace("/jon/i", "hans");

$("#output").html(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="output"></p>
```

I simply try to replace "jon" with "hans" by using regular expressions.
But It does not work.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8xkr40c/)

I informed my selve [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

EDIT: My question is obviously completly different from the "duplicate".

Comment: `name = name.replace(/jon/i, "hans");` - no quotes.

Comment: When you wrapped your regex in quotes, JS only sees it as a string. Instead of quotes, regular expressions are wrapped (usually) in slashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `""` in replace.you are matching the string not the regex pattern

```js
var name = "jon snow"

name = name.replace(/jon/i, "hans");

$("#output").html(name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the quotations; there is a regex literal in JS:

```
let regex = /jon/i; // this is a regex
let str = "foo"; // this is a string
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `replace` with a regular expression, don't put quotes around the first parameter--just the slashes with the regex options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the regex expression  without ""

```
var name = "jon snow"

name = name.replace(/jon/i, "hans");

$("#output").html(name);
```